# How to analyze time series data with very few samples for response variable

Tags: r, regression, time-series, medicine

I want to use R to model a person's blood-iron level to predict how it changes over time. My response variable is blood-iron level and my explanatory variables are related to diet, use of different kinds of supplements (drops, tablets, blood infusion), etc. My data is in time-series format with one row per day spanning approximately one year.

The quirk is that I only have four values for my response variable. It feels strange to model this as a time series with ~350 data points if the response variable will almost always be NA.

Is there a simpler approach? Should I "dplyr" the data frame into only four rows somehow?

I am ultimately hoping that the model would estimate the effect on blood-iron level of:
- One day of time passing.
- One day of eating an iron-rich diet.
- One day of taking supplement X/Y/Z.

But I have not approached this kind of problem in R before.

Comment: I don't think you have enough data to make a statistical model that would yield results with any degree of confidence.

Comment: I would like to do the modelling all the same if only as an exercise. It will be satisfying to test it with new data in the future even if the confidence band is very large.

I wonder if I should take a Bayesian approach because there is some prior information i.e. the nominal iron content of each supplement. That might partly compensate for the lack of data?